# Page doesn't get refreshed when a comment is added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, page-refresh

Problem: When I create a comment which belongs to a post, the page doesn't get refreshed even through redirection. I know Ajax can handle this well, but I am wondering why it doesn't get refreshed. Of course the comment gets saved well to the comments table, so the page gets refreshed when I hit the f5 key manually.

I am using Windows 10, Ruby 2.2.4 and Rails 4.2.6.

[image]

**models/bulletin.rb**

```
class Bulletin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bulletin
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**controllers/bulletins_controller.rb**

```
class BulletinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bulletin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @bulletins = Bulletin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @bulletin = Bulletin.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @bulletin = Bulletin.new(bulletin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bulletin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bulletin, notice: 'Bulletin was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bulletin.update(bulletin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bulletin, notice: 'Bulletin was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bulletin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bulletins_url, notice: 'Bulletin was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_bulletin
      @bulletin = Bulletin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bulletin_params
      params.require(:bulletin).permit(:title, :description, :post_type)
    end
end
```

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_bulletin
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = @bulletin.posts.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = @bulletin.posts.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = @bulletin.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@post.bulletin, @post], notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@post.bulletin, @post], notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bulletin_posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def set_bulletin
    @bulletin = Bulletin.find(params[:bulletin_id])
  end

  def set_post
    @post = @bulletin.posts.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :picture, :picture_cache)
  end
end
```

**controllers/comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post
  before_action :set_comment, only: :destroy

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.save

    redirect_to [@post.bulletin, @post]
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

**views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
<h2><%= bulletin_name params[:bulletin_id] %></h2>

<table class='table'>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <td><%= @post.title %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Content</th>
    <td><%= @post.content %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Created at</th>
    <td><%= @post.created_at %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bulletin_post_path(@post.bulletin, @post), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', bulletin_posts_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>

<%= render "comments/comments" %>
```

Comment: You're creating them via ajax?

Comment: Do you want to add the comments to the page without refreshing at all? Or just refresh the page via AJAX?

Comment: Not yet. I thought the whole page should be refreshed.

Comment: I want the whole page to be refreshed.

Comment: Could you show us the form and any JS if it exists?

Comment: I am not using any JS yet. The whole page should get refreshed without Ajax, right?